# VBA out of stack error

Tags: vba, excel

I have several subs which call onto each other when a OnKey event is pressed. After a while, the call stack builds up and i get a "out of stack" error.  Is there a method to clear the stack? Or at least end the sub when I'm not using it?
EG.

```
Sub MoveRight()
    if GetKeyState(vbKeyDown) <0 then MoveDown
  ...
  ...
sub MoveDown
    if GetKeyState(vbKeyRight) < 0 then MoveRight
  ...
  ...
 etc
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/126090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Out of Stack" is a Severe Fatal error.  The way to clear it is to restart Excel.  Though it is possible that just restarting VBA would be sufficient, I sure wouldn't trust it.

The problem here is that you have written a pair of methods with infinite recursion in them.  DON'T DO THAT.  The simplest general fix to this is to have your routines set static flags to prevent re-entry:

```
Sub MoveRight()
    Static InUse As Boolean
    If InUse Then Exit Sub
    InUse = True
    if GetKeyState(vbKeyDown) <0 then MoveDown
  ...
  ...
    InUse = False
End Sub
```

A more specific fix would require knowledge of what you are actually trying to do, which looks highly suspect at this point.

Comment: Hello I am trying to recreate the game of snake. Therefore I need to be able to repeatidly make OnKey events even during the execution of one sub. This fix does take care of the error however now my little "square" can not move in the direection it moved before.

Comment: Don't write it recursively.  Most professional languages do not have tail-recursion optimization and so will run out of stack after several thousand recursions.  Rewrite it to be iterative, for which there is no limit in VBA and most other such lagnuages.

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained. @user3221162: This snake game are you creating on a userform or a spreadsheet? If on a userform, you can take advantage of the keydown event

Comment: @user3221162: See these two examples [ONE](http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/downloads/display.php?id=76) and [TWO](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?157478-VB6-Snake-game-source-code). Barry , sorry for hijacking the comments.

Comment: I rewrote it in iterative. It works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Code shown is a bit criptic, but, if you press "down" and "right" at same time, your code do a circular call between subs, that is a loop of calls that never ever returns, so stack will overflows in seconds.
It will better to check keys outside subs (pseudocode):

```
if (key_down is pressed)
    call do_move_down
if (key_right is pressed)
    call do_move_right
...
...
```

Comment: Hello, I tried doing that at first, however i can not move my piece until After the sub is finished. Therefore I had to put my key events inside the sub.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling into your `MoveRight()` and `MoveDown()` methods recursively.

You test calls to `GetKeyState` should sit outside of your stubs / event handlers.

A wider question might be why you need these calls at all if you already have the `OnKey` event correctly configured.

Comment: I actually took them off. I apologize, what I meant by onkey events would be testing if the arrow keys are pressed. The reason I did this is because I'm recreating the game of snake, so I need to be able to call different subs during the execution of one sub.